# Run JS Function when PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I got a Javascript function called edit like this :

```
function edit(id){
    window.opener.location.href='../../../index.php?mi=<?php echo $mi1?>&id='+id;
    //window.close();
}
```

It already work if i use a href so i need to click the link

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="edit('<?php echo $_POST["id"]?>');">
    <?php echo $_POST["id"]?>
</a>
```

Then i want to run the function when i save / update data

```
if(isset($_POST["save"])){
   ...
   ...
    echo "  <script>$(document).ready(function(){edit(".$_POST["id"].")};</script>";
}
```

But it didn't work, did i do something wrong ?

Comment: syntax error. `<script>$(document).ready(function(){ edit(".$_POST["id"]."); });</script>` you should check browser console too if there is other JS error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
echo "<script>$(document).ready(function(){edit(".$id.")});</script>";
```

you have used double quotation like this `edit(".$_POST["id"].")`.

also closing `)` is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
if(isset($_POST["save"])){
    echo "<script>$(document).ready(function(){edit(".$_POST['id'].")};</script>";
}
```